# Should I Explicitly Spec my Helpers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, bdd, rspec-rails

While rspec automatically creates specs for any helpers created by the Rails generators, I was wondering if other Rails developers find it important/useful to spec the helpers in *real-world* or if they often don't bother, since the helpers are often tested by proxy through testing of the components that use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I do test helper methods, because I like to test them in isolation. If the following feature specs fails I know I probably made a mistake in my test setup because I already ensured that the helper method works.

It is also easier to test all possible scenarios. If you want to test all possibilities as part of a whole you need more test setup and sacrifice performance.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you want to write tests for everything, but in real world with time constraints, it is not uncommon to skip simple helper method tests because you implicitly test them while building the actual test. In the same way some developers may skip private method tests.